# Erros ao tentar gerar um apk assinada, após facebook login ser acrescentado

Tags: android

Acrescentei o facebooklogin em app, funciona corretamente. 
Mas ao gerar uma apk assinada, ele reclama, que não há tradução para o português da `<string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">11111</string>` 
Abaixo o erro:

> Error:(4) Error: "fb_login_protocol_scheme" is not translated in "pt"
>   (Portuguese) [MissingTranslation]

Mas, se coloco ela também no pt/strings é me retornado este erro:

> Error:(91) Error: Resources referenced from the manifest cannot vary
>   by configuration (except for version qualifiers, e.g. -v21.) Found
>   variation in pt [ManifestResource]

Como posso resolver esta questão?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é o melhor a se fazer, mas, isto funcionou para mim.

Gradle module app:

```
   buildTypes {
        release {
.....
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
            }
        }
    }
```